# Could not find a declaration file for module datepicker even if types are installed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-datepicker

i have a provate repo with a uikit which i installed on a nextjs project.
my prod build fails with following error:

*Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-datepicker'. '../node_modules/react-datepicker/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-datepicker` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-datepicker';*

but on my uikit repo i have the datepicker type installed and the build there works fine.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

just run `npm install --save @types/react-datepicker`

and rerun